# nodejs: sqlite3 how to update or edit a json inside a json

Tags: node.js

```
db.all( "UPDATE Servers SET "+server+" = JSON_SET( '"+row[0].channels+"', ... ) WHERE id = '"+message.guild.id+"'", (error, row) =>
{
 return message.reply("The channel " + channel + " was set up for "+server+" command successfully." );
});

    {
"setwelcome":{"id":0,"msg":"Welcome to "},"setleave":{"id":0,"msg":"Good bye"},"setlog":0,"emojis":"true","music":0,"roles":{"onJoinEvent":{"status":"false","roles":[]},"onMessageReact":{"status":"false","roles":[],"id":[]}}}
```

i would like to know how to edit or update a  json inside a json in nodejs thanks.

Comment: Yow, this is ripe for SQL injection!  Not only does this cause potential security issues, it also creates a whole mess of bugs, which you're undoubtedly running into.  Use parameterized queries rather than simply concatenating data into the query.

Comment: okay bro, i will use it, thanks. But i need to solve my problem any idea?